# How to permanently set CPU power management to the powersave governor?

Tags: boot, power-management, cpufreq

I'm currently using this:

```
cpupower frequency-set --governor powersave
```

but it resets after each reboot.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance

Answer (score 25):

For 16.04 there's one more step to add to Jayen's answer. The complete set of steps are

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
echo 'GOVERNOR="powersave"' | sudo tee /etc/default/cpufrequtils
sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

The last step disables the "ondemand" daemon, which would otherwise overwrite the changes created by cpufrequtils.

See also [How I can disable CPU frequency scaling and set the system to performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance)

You might also consider adding, for example, `MAX_SPEED="2GHz"` to `/etc/default/cpufrequtils` if you have an overheating, say, 2.2GHz processor, to limit the maximum possible speed.

Comment: how to revert this change?

Comment: Can you still switch to the ondemand governor temporarily, using `cpufreq-set`, after disabling it with `update-rc.d`?

Comment: Did you mean "override" or "overwrite" the changes created by cpufrequtils? I believe it should be former.

Comment: Note, for ubuntu 18.04+ use `sudo systemctl disable ondemand` to disable ondemand

Comment: This is not recommended because the file may already exist, so you'd a second line of GOVERNOR=

Answer (score 14):

To set the governor permanently to powersave, firstly install cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

And then edit the `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` file and change `GOVERNOR` to `"powersave"` (`GOVERNOR="powersave"`). You can do this automatically by using the following command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^GOVERNOR=.*/GOVERNOR="powersave"/' /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils
```

From here: [Prevent Your Laptop From Overheating With Thermald And Intel P-State](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)

Comment: Editing the /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils is the wrong approach because this file contains the following code:
`if [ -f /etc/default/cpufrequtils ] ; then
        . /etc/default/cpufrequtils`

Therefore the default governor should be set as follow.
`echo 'GOVERNOR="powersave"' | sudo tee /etc/default/cpufrequtils`

Comment: thanks, you save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 14):

Based on Alin's answer, but will persist when cpufrequtils is upgraded:

To set the governor permanently to powersave, firstly install cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

And then create/edit the `/etc/default/cpufrequtils` file (which is read from `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils`) and set `GOVERNOR="powersave"`. You can do this automatically by using the following command:

```
echo 'GOVERNOR="powersave"' | sudo tee /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

And if you are on Ubuntu 16.04 or later, you need to disable the built-in service that sets the governor to `ondemand`:

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

Comment: There I am posting last step for Ubuntu 18.04 or later:
And if you are on Ubuntu 18.04 or later, you need to disable the built-in service that sets governor to `ondemand`:
`sudo systemctl disable ondemand`