# TLP governor settings not taking effect

Tags: tlp

I have TLP installed with these config lines:

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave
```

But my governors are still ondemand. I know how to do it with cpufrequtils as mentioned in [How to permanently set CPU power management to the powersave governor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410860/how-to-permanently-set-cpu-power-management-to-the-powersave-governor), but why is the TLP settings not taking effect?

I dont have `cpufrequtils` installed. But I do have `cpupower`. But does that matter?

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem, the solution is to disable `cpufrequtils` and `ondemand` service

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove 
sudo update-rc.d -f cpufrequtils remove
```