# How to set "Performance" instead of "Powersave" as default?

Tags: 17.04, cpufreq

When I start my Unity desktop the CPU indicator shows only one bar and it is set to *Powersave*. When I switch to *Performance* I have to enter an admin users password.

But after system restart my CPU is back in *Powersave*. How to set *Performance* as the default, so I don't have to switch it after every restart?

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/445595/639369 help? In short edit /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils to set CPU governor to (in this case) performance on startup.

Answer (score 31):

## Performance and Powersave Governor Policies

There are various options for setting CPU governor policy described in Ask Ubuntu and other websites:

- [How to permanently set CPU power management to the powersave governor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410860/how-to-permanently-set-cpu-power-management-to-the-powersave-governor)
- [Prevent your laptop from overheating](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)
- [How I can disable CPU frequency scaling and set the system to performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance)
- [CPU Frequency scaling in Linux](https://idebian.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/cpu-frequency-scaling-in-linux/)
- [Avoiding CPU Speed Scaling – Running CPU At Full Speed](http://www.servernoobs.com/avoiding-cpu-speed-scaling-in-modern-linux-distributions-running-cpu-at-full-speed-tips/)

Keep in mind most websites suggest leaving CPU governing at `Powersave`. I'm on a laptop and found using Intel's ThermalD and P-State technologies coupled with TLP power management has best result for frequencies, fan speed and temperature.

## Summarizing above links

To summarize achieving your goal from the above answers use:

Install cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Then edit the following file (if it doesn't exist, create it):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

And add the following line to it:

```
GOVERNOR="performance"
```

Save and exit.

For changes take effect, run:

```
sudo systemctl restart cpufrequtils
```

Then you can run `cpufreq-info` to see informations about your cpu frequency, governor and more:

```
$ cpufreq-info
    current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.90 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
```

---

As per this Q&A: [Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084727/307523)

If you want performance governor all the time you need to edit `/etc/rc.local` and insert these lines before the last line containing `exit 0`:

```
sleep 120 # Give CPU startup routines time to settle.
cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```

To setup `/etc/rc.local` in 18.04 see: [How to Enable `/etc/rc.local` with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

Comment: This is also applicable to Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 just in case anyone is wondering...

Comment: Appears to be working in 20.04 Kubuntu. How can you revert this change in the same session without rebooting? Here's the scenario, I want to set the governor to performance before I enter a game and back to powersave after I'm done.

Comment: @el-banto I added a new section to the answer. In your case you can try: `echo powersave | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` when game is finished. Hopefully that works as it is the simplest method.

Comment: Thanks, can I just echo performance as well instead of using cpufrequtils?

Comment: @el-banto Yes that is the simplest, but you have to wait 1 minute after boot because it is set to performance during first minute to speed up boot then set to powersave.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The echo command didn't work unfortunately. Even with sudo, I'm getting permission denied errors.

Comment: @el-banto The `sudo` goes in a different spot using `tee` command. For example: `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: Cheers, it works great now!

Answer (score 7):

I cannot comment because I have low reputation but I want to add the accepted answer. You will also need to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart
```

for this to take effect on your system. You should then see your frequencies hovering around the max listed and

```
current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.90 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
```

When you type cpufreq-info

Comment: Thanks for that. I've submitted a edit to the accepted answer with your suggestion;

Comment: You can authorization to other sites, like stackoverflow to gain 100 reputation for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04.02 LTS and installing cpufrequtils by `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`, made it possible to reduce the max CPU-speed. A nice option to have as the fan has stopped working.

After looking at the info by `cpufreq-info`, I created a file by `sudo nano /etc/default/cpufrequtils`, and wrote into it as in picture below. I found out it was of use to also set a value for min speed.

[image]

Lastly the command to make the change take action `sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart`, resulting in this output from `cpufreq-info`:

[image]

To be clear - this is off course not my own findings, only a result of conclusions made from other earlier questions, comments, and answers on this forum. Especially the answer in this very question from
WinEunuuchs2Unix.