# Ubuntu suddenly slows down after a while

Tags: performance

I have a new laptop with dual boot (Windows 11 / Ubuntu 20.04).
When using Ubuntu, after some time (could be between few minutes to a few hours), it suddenly becomes painfully slow. Interestingly, every time this happens, the fans also slow down.
I've tried changing from "powersave" to "performance", as described here:
[How to set "Performance" instead of "Powersave" as default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929884/how-to-set-performance-instead-of-powersave-as-default)
, with no success. I've had this problem ever since I got the laptop a month ago. Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Hello. It is not clear if it is an issue in both of the OS.

Comment: It only happens on ubuntu.