# How to set cpu governor to performance in Ubuntu 22 server

Tags: server, kernel, cpufreq, governor

I have already read similar posts about this but none of them is related to my situation.

When using the following command :

```
cpupower frequency-info
```

I get the following result :

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

It says

> no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU

I read that I need to enable Intel turbo, but I don't have the following file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`.

How can I set CPU governor to performance in my Ubuntu 22 server?
I have 8 cores of CPU .

**EDIT:** My kernel version is 5.15.0-94-generic and the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo ; find /sys/devices/system/cpu` can be found [here at PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/0giiKfm2).

Comment: `cpupower` requires root access. Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `sudo cpupower frequency-info` instead.

Comment: @terdon I ran the command as root . the output is the same .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set as default Performance mode on Ubuntu 20.04 instead of Powersave?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322492/how-to-set-as-default-performance-mode-on-ubuntu-20-04-instead-of-powersave)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No because he wants to change governor from powersave to performance but I don't even have those enabled and I get : no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU . don't know how to enable intel pstate . Nothing works .

Comment: @lostsoul6 You can set `performance` without installing `cpufreq` See the answers (including the one I just posted) on the duplicate.

Comment: Please [edit] with `cat /proc/cpuinfo ; find /sys/devices/system/cpu`

Comment: @DanielT the output of that command was long and askubuntu didn't allow me to post it . here is the pastebin : pastebin.com/0giiKfm2

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix , I saw your post on that link . the commands don't return anything : sudo systemctl disable ondemand.service
Failed to disable unit: Unit file ondemand.service does not exist . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory

Comment: @lostsoul6 Thanks for trying. I retracted my close vote on the duplicate question.

Comment: Seems like the cpufreq scaling_driver isn't loading. What is `dmesg | grep intel_pstate` ? https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020273

Comment: @DanielT it returns : [    1.037543] intel_pstate: CPU model not supported . My server's CPU is : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz

Comment: Either it's really not supported or you need to update your kernel to the 6.5 version using HWE: https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/1004020